# Bits/second Versus Bits/symbol

Tags: information-theory

Can someone reconcile between the channel capacity in bits/symbol and in bits/second? Are they related to the definition of channel capacity in terms of mutual information and the other in terms of SNR and bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

bits/symbol is the capacity of the encoder 
bits/second is the capacity of the channel

If you have to send n symbols, the number of bits needed depends on the encoder. After converting to bits, channel sends the bits and this is measured in no. of bits/second. Band width has no relation to bits/second. It's just the frequency domain of the channel carrier. Carrier just carries the information. It's not the information by itself.